# Why the settings of my SSIS container changes back automatically?

Tags: ssis

I am taking over a SSIS package which was developed and running on another server, say `Server-01`. I am working on this package with MS Visual Studio 2008.

Now, I am trying to run it on my server `Server-02`.

So I changed the settings of some `SQL Task` boxes and their related data sources from `Server-01` to `Server-02`, then pressed the `OK`. After this, I closed the setting panel and reopened it, it looks fine, all my changes have been recorded.

Then I run the boxes in `Development` mode. As it stopped, I open the boxes which I've changed, then find everything was changed back to its initial status.

May I know what is wrong with my operation, and how can I over come it?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you've resolved your issue. If you haven't then you'll need to provide us with more details, concrete ones, about how your package is structured, screenshots will help in this matter. Also, install [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) It's free and will provide visual cues when an element has an Expression assigned to it, or if it has properties set via Configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wrestling with the problem for a while, here are two methods I found. They may not formal, but it suits my case.

Method 1: I went to `SSIS`->`Variables`, then change the value of the variable there.

Method 2: I had one variable which cannot be changed via above method, so I opened its property panel, and changed the expression and assigned a new value to it.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong, or if there are better ways to settle this.

Thanks a lot.